# update result table only when the source table data is changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

We have a result table which contains data from 5-6 source tables. The data is displayed in the weekly basis. We have decided to write a stored procedure and call it from a SQL Server job to pull the data into the result table on a weekly basis.

If any data is changed/updated in source tables within a week's period, we have to update those records only in the result table. Now we are considering two approaches to do this:

1. Create triggers to update the result table whenever the change/update occurs in source table within same week.
2. use `[modified date]` column to identify the modified records in source tables and update the same in result table.

My questions are:

1. Do we have any other lightweight approach to do the same in SQL Server or SSIS?
2. For loading data on a weekly basis into result table, do we have any other method apart from a SQL Server job in SQL Server or SSIS?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you only care about the status from one week to the next or do you need to capture all of the changes during each week? The first is easier to handle with a scheduled job and a [rowversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) column in each table. The second is something a trigger can handle. "It depends" clause: How much data? How often does it change? Reads vs. writes balance? ...

Comment: There is pleanty of of data. It will change too often since all the source tables are transaction tables. I need to capture all the data changes.

Comment: Can any one tell me , do we can use Change Data Capture IN SSIS for these scenarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers to questions:

1. Consider [Change Data Capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895315.aspx).
2. Windows Task Scheduler can run executables on a scheduled basis, such as sqlcmd.exe. And there are many 3rd party task/job scheduling solutions.

SSIS uses SQL Agent jobs for its scheduling. Ultimately, SSIS, jobs, and almost every solution must use T-SQL to accomplish what is desired.

Change Data Capture is slightly different (hence why I wrote "almost"). Its logreader or sp_replcmds use *internal function calls* to detect (SQL Server's always logged) changes, which means CDC is relatively "lightweight", in terms of performance impact.

Comments on considered approaches:

1. Carefully test performance and logic when using triggers. Triggers
   run in the scope of a transaction, so they add overhead that will
   impact transaction performance, and (when improperly written) can
   cause unexpected rollbacks. I would favor CDC over this approach.
2. Instead of a [Modified date], consider adding a [rowversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx)
   column to each of the 4-5 source tables. Add 4-5 binary(8) columns
   (one for each rowversion) to the target table or another table that
   has a 1:1 relationship to the target table. Add each of the 4-5
   source table's primary key columns to the target table or the 1:1
   table. Insert the source tables' primary key values and their
   rowversion values into the target table or the 1:1 table. When a
   rowversion value for the joined key value differs, the source
   table's row has been modified. When a row is absent in the target
   table or the 1:1 table, a row has been inserted into the source
   table. I would favor CDC over this approach.

Comment: Thanks for the Solution. But I have a doubt over CDC implementation. Do i need to insert the the updated rows from the source tables and update it into destination tables by using CDC?

Comment: You use CDC to identify the changes - there is no need to alter your existing source tables (unless they unwisely do not have a primary key). If a history of changes is unneeded, use Change Tracking. Both provide functions that identify changes to rows and columns. You use those functions to develop/write your own insert, update, or delete statements for your target table. Because the source table is not modified, CDC or CT can easily harness an existing design. If a table has no primary key, consider creating a surrogate PK that harnesses the identity property.